Webhook not working after activated for Lead Sync API
What I am doing is to activate Lead Sync API, and register Webhook, Webhook URL validated, then i add leadgen form from our page for the lead request form LeadForm. the issue is i don't receive any hook notification when i submit the form. The webhook subscribe in Organic Lead Type.
Activate Lead Sync API, Subscribe Webhook
No receive any hook notification

Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.
